# AsyncKeyDown pressed key value

Tags: intraweb

Using Intraweb in Delphi,

Is there a way to find AsyncKeyDown pressed key value?

I know its somehow inside EventParams: TStringList but I only can see it through the Local variable list at runtime like this, string = 'char=i', and I cannot really get it out from there as a char unless I make a special function to pull it from there, so I'm thinking if there is a simple way to just get the pressed key as char from AsyncKeyDown ?

Answer (score 2):

I know it's been a long time since the question was asked. But it will be good for those who still need it. I used it and working. You can get it as char as following:

http://www.devsuperpage.com/search/Articles.aspx?G=2&ArtID=52557

```
procedure TfrmLHasta.edSuzAsyncKeyDown(Sender: TObject;
  EventParams: TStringList);
var
  lKey: char;
begin
  lKey := Chr(StrToInt(EventParams.Values['which']));
  //  WebApplication.ShowMessage(lKey);
  if lKey = #13 then DoSomething;
end;
```